# Hold the max value of a signal in Simulink for specified amount of time

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, simulink

I have a swinging pendulum in Simulink and want some valve to stay open for a specific amount of time (say 2 sec or so) at the moment of maximum excitation. Finding the point of maximum excitation was no problem, I used a IF ELSE block on the derivative of the angle (angular velocity) and if abs(angular velocity)<0.1 (or so) the moment of maximum excitation is reached. The problem is holding this value high for a specific amount of time.
In the image I specified the signal I have now and the required signal (Paint, so not so exact):

[image: input and required output signal]

I have tried a [delay](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/delay.html), but this only delays everything a bit. A [zero-order-hold](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/zeroorderhold.html?refresh=true) didn't work either, it sometimes missed the signals and the output became zero (unknown phase and period of the input signal, else it might work)
I also tried [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2014/08/06/how-do-you-hold-the-value-of-a-signal/), it didn't work as I didn't have a input signal of the hold, I only have the input signal shown in the figure...

What block/subsystem should I use to create this kind of signal?

Comment: Do you have access to Stateflow?  Although this can be done in pure Simulink you need to jump through multiple hoops to set up a triggered sybsystem and an enables subsystem each with appropriate logic and counters in them, whereas it's almost trivial in Stateflow.

Comment: You would need to generate the signal which determines how long you hold. Otherwise you may need to write your own block.

Comment: I have never heared of Stateflow, but I do have acces to it and am downloading and installing it currently. I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: managed to get it to work with Stateflow, thanks for the suggestion!